# closing an open div when body / html element is clicked in meteor

Tags: meteor, velocity.js

so i'm working on a meteor project and am trying to get a drop down menu to close when the user clicks outside of it. i've done this before using jquery and normal html but this time we're using velocity.js and meteor.

so on the link that opens the drop down div, i have this:

```
Template.layout.events({
'click #profile-btn': function () {
    if (userTog == false) {
        $('#user-menu').velocity("fadeIn", { duration: 150 });
        userTog = true;
    }
    else if (userTog == true) {
        $('#user-menu').velocity("fadeOut", { duration: 150 });
        userTog = false;
    }        
},
.....
```

and then i use a meteor package to deal with events on the body as this isnt supported right now..

```
Template.body.events({
'click html': function(e, data, tpl) {
    userTog = false;
    $('#user-menu').velocity("fadeOut", { duration: 150 });
    e.stopPropagation();
}});
```

however the above is just not working.. it basically just makes the menu appear then disappear straight away. is it something to do with velocity.js, meteor or am i just doing it plain wrong ?!?

any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to make a material design select box, so I feel your pain :-). Here's how I solved it:

Normally, you can only focus an `input` or an `anchor`. A trick I stumbled upon is that using `tabindex="0"` in your element attributes allows it to gain focus, even if it's a `div`. What's this mean? Well, if you can `focus()` an element, that means you can `blur()` it.  So, when you click the button for the dropdown, add a line at the end of the event handler like `$('.dropdown-menu').focus()`. Then, to escape that, just create an event handler like `'blur .dropdown-menu': function() {*..hide..*}`. That way, you don't have these ugly global event watchers.

The downside is that you get a glowing blue outline (for accessibility reasons). You can get rid of this by having a line like `outline: 0;` in your css.

PS, the reason why yours wasn't working is because `'click #profile-btn'` bubbles up to the body, so it executes both. To fix it, you need to stop that bubblin via `e.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: hi matt, thanks for the above.. but i cant seem to get it working.. as for the suggestion about e.stopPropagation() i have this in my code but it's obviously not working.. have you used it before in meteor ?

Comment: i don't see a `stopPropagation` in your #profile-btn event handler, it should be the first line. console log your html event handler with the event param & check out the `target` and `currentTarget` to see what's calling it. But seriously...ditch the global event handlers. you'll soon learn they are a nightmare to keep in order.